Advice on applying new peel-and-stick tiles in my kitchen
I'd like to put down some new peel-and-stick vinyl tiles in my kitchen. The kitchen already has old, somewhat beat up peel-and-stick tiles stuck onto what I believe is an even older linoleum (?) floor. I am on a tight-ish timeline of about 2 weeks (self-imposed, but I have some major appliances being delivered soon and would like to get the floor updated before they arrive).
My questions:

With the condition the floor is in, would it be a mistake to stick the new tiles directly on top of the old ones? Aside from the edges where the floor goes under where the dishwasher and stove will be, the floor is quite level, just dirty and (imo) ugly. I've seen people saying that vinyl tile sticks well to a vinyl layer underneath, so that is appealing. Alternatively, I could pull up the existing tiles, but I'm a little nervous what condition the floor underneath that will be in, and that maybe it wouldn't be any better of a surface to stick the tiles to.
If I decide to stick new tile right on top of the existing tiles, any thoughts on how to prep the surface (besides vigorous cleaning) that could increase the tiles' odds of sticking? I am aware that I would probably need to remove and replace the quarter rounds around the edge of the room to do this.
Some people recommend using additional adhesive, such as Loctite, to help the tiles stick even better. Thoughts?
Would it make sense/be advisable to use some kind of self-leveler to fill in some of that area where the stove will go (in the photos currently it has a metal table with some small appliances) where the old tiles don't extend all the way to the wall? Or maybe just put down 2 layers of tile there to even it out? I had to remove an old, 36-inch oven from that space, and my new stove will not cover all that floor area, so I'd like the tiles to fill all the way in to the wall if possible.

For some personal context, I am on quite a tight budget because my fiancé and I are dealing with some debt. It will probably be several years before we have the ability to do a more serious kitchen floor redo, and we may not stay in this house for long enough for that investment to be worthwhile even then. So I am looking for a solution that will provide a significant aesthetic upgrade that can last us at least a couple of years and require a minimum of cost and labor input. I know that's probably not what folks in this forum like to hear - I'm a very new DIYer/homeowner in general, and while I love my house and want to take excellent care of it, there are some areas where we have to compromise! I just want to make sure that if I'm going to do something the cheap way I at least come in as prepared/informed as possible.
Thank you in advance for all advice and input! I'm a little bit anxious about doing this kind of thing all on my own for the first time (so any words of encouragement would be greatly appreciated, lol).






Please see [ask], then revise to ask just one question in your post.

Loctite is a manufacturer, not a product. Please revise to be more specific. You wouldn't use a "self-leveler" for any of this. If anything, you'd use an "embossing leveler" or other skimcoat.

If you put new peel and stick over old peel and stick and the old peel and stick starts to come up you will have a big problem. Same with sheet flooring, that will show any imperfection underneath.
However if you put LVP over the old peel and stick it will be a bonded platform (Floating floor) over the old peel and stick. If there are any issues with the old P&S trying to come loose, there will be no problem since the new floor as an entire unit will keep the old P&S down.  It can't shift, lift or move.
The P&S will serve you for maybe 5 years. The LVP will last 15 to 20.
Do some hard thinking before starting this project...Just saying.

@mM2C,  thanks for the edit...had brain fade this morning.

The pictures are of a floor with considerably better hopes for a new layer sticking than the text description implied.
You have to clean it, and get it throughly dry after cleaning it. Yes, the moldings need to come off.
Find stick-on the same thickness as what's on there now for the bottom of the alcoves, then your top layer can go onto a level surface. I guess you'll need two layers to get under the stove where it's bare wood as opposed to old lino or vinyl sheet. Or you can use various sorts of filler to level those areas.
I've had good luck with the adhesive provided on the peel and stick. It does help if the tiles and room are warm.
IMHO if you're going to add adhesive, you might as well put down VCT (Vinyl Composition Tile) which comes with no adhesive on it anyway, and is tough enough for commercial kitchen and school use, and at my local suppliers is not much more than (and less than some) peel and stick options.


I would suggest at least considering vinyl sheet flooring if you can manage to take the time to make an accurate pattern of your floorspace with stiff builders paper (red rosin or the like) cut to fit and carefully taped so you can cut the vinyl sheet accurately from the pattern, then roll it up, get it through the door, unroll it and done (well, you still need to level the under-stove section first.) My quick glance at suppliers local  to me suggests it usually costs less than peel and stick tiles, and it has no seams (at least if the room is less than 12 feet wide) which means it has no place to peel up from (other than the edges which you trap under molding, and/or adhere with double-stick tape or glue just at the edges, etc.) and it's also easier to keep clean without all those seams/joints.
Be sure to select appropriate sheet vinyl for a loose-lay or perimeter bond installation. Gluing down the whole floor is considerably more work, but is required if you choose one that needs it.
If you do go there, it might be worth investigating if the bottom layer is really fully adhered or not without committing to ripping it out unless it proves to be not particularly attached.

Thank you for this very helpful reply! I'm glad to hear the floor is looking better than it seems to me... I might be a bit paranoid. Some people online are really against leaving old peel and stick down, so I wanted someone to take a look at my specific case, so thank you for that! I'll definitely look into sheet flooring, I hadn't really considered that. Thanks again!
